# delete file (with unlink()) after using it for PDO connection in database class: permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have the following php-script test.php:

```
<?php

class Database {

    public $databaseConnection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->databaseConnection = new PDO('sqlite:test.sq3', 0, 0);
        $this->databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        self::query('CREATE TABLE...');
    }

    function query($sql, $params = NULL){
    ...
    }   

    function insert($table, $data){
    ...
    }
}

$database = new Database();

$database->insert(...);//insert something into Database

$userData = $database->query(...);//getting $userData after query

$username = $userData;

print_r($username);

$database = null;

unlink('test.sq3');
```

So everythings working fine until the last line.

```
Permission denied in F:\...\test.php on line 75
```

I already looked up following things in the documentation:

```
Instruction separation:
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

```
Connections and Connection management (of PDO-objects):
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

So to end the connection of a PDO-ocject to the database it has to set = null.

After that I tried:

```
unset($database);
```

Permission denied. So I made an extern file delete.php:

```
<?php unlink('test.sq3'); ?>
```

This script is working. So I can delete the file in another script.
And the last thing I tried (with =null and unset()):

```
include('delete.php');
```

Which did not work neither. But the main thing about is that I don´t have a clue why I can´t delete the file in the same script.

So how can I delete the database-file in the same script?

Comment: When run directly by you, the command checks YOU to see if you have permission to delete the file. When run through a web server, the command checks to see if the SERVER has permission to delete the file. So, check the log files (yes - the log files) and see the error. It is very likely a file permission error.

Comment: @kainaw Looks like a windows system. Permissions are almost never an issue on windows unless OP has a very unusual/tailored environment

Comment: Check that the `query()` and `insert()` etc methods close and null their Statement handles. These may be holding the class active and in memory and therefore foiling your delete

Comment: You are closing the PDO connecting wrongly. I would create a destructor in that Database class to set the variable databaseConnection to null when the class is done executing. You're currently setting your Database to null instead of the PDO instance. Perhaps that might be keeping the file in use during the execution of the script, which might block the deletion of the file.

Comment: At:kainaw I am using WAMP 2.5 so the errors are in php_error.log and there is written the same message. So what I have to searching for ? 
||
At:RiggsFolly Can you define an unusal / tailored environment ? 
||
At:Matheus I will try it out

Comment: I set an destructor first with =null and then with unset to closing the PDO connection but thats not working neither. Any other clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I find out whats wrong. In the method query which looked like:

```
    function query($sql, $params = NULL){
        $s = $this->databaseConnection->prepare($sql);
        if(is_array($params)){
            $s->execute(array_values($params));
            return $s;
        }
        $s->execute((array) $params);
        return $s;
    }
```

As you can see there is no fetch()-statement, because I wanted to try out whats happen without it. So you get an Output just like:

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT username FROM user WHERE numberoflogins = ? )
```

I skipped it because I thought it wasn´t really necessary when it works.

Well, atleast I don´t have a clue whats this PDO method has something todo with the end of my script because I unset every variable which has something todo with the PDO object but the point is that now he deletes the file.